# Is there a way to convert with pair of rows in a table into one row in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

| ID | dtCheck | type | placeId | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-13 13:00:00 | in | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-12-13 13:10:00 | in | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-12-13 14:00:00 | out | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-12-13 15:00:00 | in | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-12-13 16:00:00 | out | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-12-13 17:00:00 | out | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 2021-12-13 17:00:00 | in | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 2021-12-13 18:00:00 | out | 2 | 1 |

And I don't know how to write a select query to produce a result like this:

| dtCheckIn | dtCheckOut | placeId | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-13 13:00:00 | 2021-12-13 14:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-12-13 13:10:00 | 2021-12-13 17:00:00 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-12-13 15:10:00 | 2021-12-13 16:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-12-13 17:10:00 | 2021-12-13 18:00:00 | 2 | 1 |

So basically, the result will display the pair of 2 rows check in and check out into one row.

Comment: window function `LAG` or `LEAD` could help

Comment: can I have a detail? because the records in the origin table are not adjoining in order the use lead() or lag() as you recommended.

Comment: what mysql version are you using?

Comment: *So basically, the result will display the pair of 2 rows check in and check out into one row.* Does the row which have no a paired row may be ignored in the output?

Comment: *because the records in the origin table are not adjoining in order the use lead() or lag()* Incorrect. Window functions have their own ORDER BY in the window definition.

Comment: what MySql version are you using? 8.0.20, @ProGu. But I think maybe I'm wrong about lead() or lag() functions as Akina pointed out their ORDER BY. Thank you.

Comment: Does the row which have no a paired row may be ignored in the output? It should be include as dtCheckIn 2021-12-13 15:00:00 dtCheckOut NULL @Akina.

Comment: *It should be include as* And what about non-paired 'out' row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option to use `LEAD`

```
SELECT check_in, CASE WHEN type_out = 'out' THEN check_out ELSE NULL END check_out, place_id, user_id
FROM (
 SELECT dt_check check_in, `type` type_in, LEAD(dt_check) OVER w check_out, LEAD(`type`) OVER w type_out,  place_id, user_id 
 FROM in_out
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY place_id, user_id ORDER BY dt_check ASC)
) u
WHERE type_in = 'in' 
ORDER BY check_in
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5cccc5ee567f925e11cab8bebc8e155)

Comment: Your answer and Akina are right, but I marked this as accepted because of the support for the case when dtCheckout = null. Thank you, guys.

Comment: @tronglt Nothing prevents to use ```.. LEFT JOIN table t2 ..```. From the other side on version 8+ the solution with window function is, of course, more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.dtCheck dtCheckin,
       t2.dtCheck dtCheckOut,
       placeId, 
       userId
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (placeId, userId)
WHERE t1.type = 'in'
  AND t2.type = 'out'
  AND t1.dtCheck < t2.dtCheck
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t3
                   WHERE t1.dtCheck < t3.dtCheck
                     AND t3.dtCheck < t2.dtCheck 
                     AND (t1.placeId, t1.userId) = (t3.placeId, t3.userId) )
```